# Guessing Game Program

Tags: c

I've created a simple guessing game program. My problem is I'm not sure how to loop the program back to the beginning of the program once the user has guessed a wrong number. I want the program to continue asking the user for a number until he gets it right. Can someone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int value = 58;
    int guess;

    printf("Please enter a value: ");
    scanf("%i", &guess);

    if (guess == value) {
        printf("Congratulations, you guessed the right value");
    }
    else if (guess > value) {
        printf("That value is too high. Please guess again: ");
        scanf("%i", &guess);
    }
    else if (guess < value) {
        printf("That value is too low. Please guess again: ");
        scanf("%i", &guess);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you need a good book: http://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/10077

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a great spot for a `while` loop and a `break` statement.  You can use the `while` loop like this to loop infinitely:

```
while (true) {
    /* ... /*
}
```

Then, once some condition becomes true and you want to stop looping, you can use the `break` statement to exit the loop:

```
while (true) {
     /* ... */

     if (condition) break;

     /* ... */
}
```

This way, you can `break` out of the loop when the user guesses correctly.

Alternatively, you can use a `do ... while` loop whose condition checks whether the loop should exit:

```
bool isDone = false;
do {
    /* ... */

    if (condition) isDone = true;

    /* ... */
} while (!isDone);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Downvoter- Could you please comment on what's wrong with this answer?  I would love to improve it if possible.

Comment: Also note that you have to `#include <stdbool.h>` when using `false`/`true`.

Comment: That's as clean as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of looping constructs in the C syntax. They are:

- `for()`
- `while()`
- `do/while()`

Either of these should be simple to look up in whatever reference material you're using, and either is possible to use to solve this problem.

Comment: Don't forget `goto` & `setjmp()`!

Comment: "`goto` & `setjmp()`" & recursion ... in C, `main` can be called recursively :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
printf("Please enter a value: ");
do {
    scanf("%i", &guess);

    if (guess == value) {
        printf("Congratulations, you guessed the right value");
    }
    else if (guess > value) {
        printf("That value is too high. Please guess again: ");
    }
    else if (guess < value) {
        printf("That value is too low. Please guess again: ");
} while (guess != value);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `do { /*your code*/ } while(condition);`

```
do {
/*your code*/
char wannaPlayAgain;
wannaPlayAgain = getchar();
} while(wannaPlayAgain=='y');
```

Of course you should fix it in case people enter Y rather then y, but the point is you need to wrap your program in a do while loop (it will execute at least once) or a while loop (get the initial value before you enter the condition) with an initial start condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected program is

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main (void) {
    int value = 58;
    int guess;

    do
    {
        printf("please enter a value : ");
        scanf("%i", &guess);
        if(guess > value)
            printf("this value is too big, ");
        else if(guess < value)
            printf("this value is too small, ");
    }while(guess != value);

    printf("Congradulation You Guessed The Right Number. \n");
}
```